# Generalization of the triple tangent identity

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mg.metric-geometry

It is well known that if $x + y + z = \pi$ then $$\tan x \times  \tan y \times \tan z = \tan x+ \tan +\tan z.$$

I came across the following generalization of this equality:

$$\sqrt{1-k^2} {\rm sc}(x|k)\times {\rm sc}(y|k)\times{\rm sc}(z|k)\geq {\rm sc}(x|k)+ {\rm sc}(y|k)+{\rm sc}(z|k), $$
where ${\rm sc}(x|k)$ is the elliptic tangent function (by definition ${\rm sc}(x|k)=\frac{{\rm sn}(x|k)}{{\rm cn}(x|k)}$, where ${\rm sn}$ and ${\rm cn}$ are the Jacobi sine and cosine elliptic functions), and where $x+y+z=2K(k)$ ($K(k)$ is the generalization of $\pi/2$, it equals the complete elliptic integral of the first kind).

I already have an "analytic" proof of this inequality, but I would like to see a geometric proof. I am interested in any ideas!!

Comment: If you can share your analytic proof and give a link to the analytic and geometric proofs of the tangent identity, it would be easier for others to try to find an analogous geometric proof.

Answer (score 1):

For a proof of the standard triple tangent identity, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_trigonometric_identities#Miscellaneous_--_the_triple_tangent_identity). For an analytic proof of the generalized identity, one can replace $z$ by $2K(k)-x-y$ and use the [addition formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Addition_theorems) for Jacobi elliptic functions.